# Lua: How to implement os.execute() with a timeout?

Tags: lua

How can I execute an 
`os.execute("example.exe")` with a timeout of 'n' seconds in Lua?

By timeout I mean if 'example.exe' takes more than 'n' seconds to finish execution, it has to be terminated forcibly and lua script must continue executing the statements after os.execute('example.exe').

Comment: Just wait n seconds and invoke `os.execute("taskkill /im calc.exe /f")` to kill the calculator.

Comment: my variant cmd: `os.execute("start notepad.exe & ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 >nul & taskkill /im notepad.exe /f")`

Comment: @MikeV. That was smart :) There is just one problem - there could be multiple notepad open - anyway my exe is unique and hence suits my needs